# PHP Get Values from a URL using GET[]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to develop products filters for an online store I am working on. An example of what I mean is `http://www.riverisland.com/men/just-arrived`. I have managed to get a JavaScript to populate the URL when the sizes are clicked on but failed to get them remove value from URL when unchecked.

My main question here is this. Assuming I have my URL as:

`http://127.0.0.1/shop/dresses/?s=1&s=2&s=3`

How do I get my PHP to extract the values from the URL?
How do I format a SQL query to search the values gotten from the URL using any sample query?

Comment: If you GET the value for the URL you shown in your question you will get only as 3. You need to change 's' as array `s[]` and pass the values via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How do I get to achieve this as I am not good at Ajax? My form has it as name="s[]"

Comment: Complete solution? Sorry but you're expected to ask specific questions at this site. Come on, the only thing that's left is asking for a graphic design ;-P

Comment: Either change param names, or add them separated with comma: `?s=1,2,3,4` - it should be easy enough to manipulate with JS and PHP. And I agree with Alvaro ;)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Offer some help to aid me carry through. I came here seeking for assistance from advance peeps. You can willingly help if you can and care to. I'll appreciate.

Comment: Site guidelines apart, you have to understand that it's physically impossible to help you finish your app if you don't ask specific questions. Format a SQL query? Do you want us to design your database and type a SQL tutorial in the *answer* textbox?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I get your point. Just that I'm in a fix so I asked for that. I'll edit it off the question.

Comment: @Andrey.Popov Thanks for your suggestion. I'm working on it to see how I can get it working for me.

Comment: I'll answer your first question (sorry but you'll have to learn SQL in a book).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier solution is this.

Format your URL like `http://127.0.0.1/shop/dresses/?s=1,2,3` as suggested by @Andrey.Popov. Then do the below.

```
if(isset($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['s']))
{
    $e = sanitizeFunction($_GET['s']);
    $d=explode(',',$e);
}
```

`$d` now has all your $_GET['s'] values.

That's the easier way I have figured out and it works!

Comment: Your solution is faster and simpler to understand so I'm taking it as my answer but @Alvaro was on point though it needed me to know what I was doing or I get lost in understanding. This solution is just an ABC solution and worked faster for me.

How do I get the boxes for the various sizes or brands checked? Pls a last clue then I sort out the SQL

Comment: Better to populate your values from DB in a for() loop then do the below and it will work fine for you.
`<input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array($checkid[$i], $paramfromurl)){ ?>checked<?php } ?>`

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked! I got my SQL working fine too. Thanks to everyone that helped me get this working. I go over to other stuffs now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to benefit from `$_GET` and other superglobals you have to follow the rules explained at [Variables From External Sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php). Since you've chosen to have several parameters with the same name and they do not contain properly paired square brackets you're basically on your own. The manual steps you must reproduce include:

1. Extract the raw query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, e.g.:

   ```
   $query_string = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING');
   ```
2. Parse out the string. As far as I know, there aren't built-in functions that do exactly this so I'd either google for a good third-party library or write a simple parser with regular expressions or good old `explode()`.
3. Decode the URL-encoded values with `urldecode()`

Comment: I got it all working now. Will work out the SQL as I can get that done. Thanks for the lead.